# Symfony generating different folder structure than expected

Tags: php, symfony

I am reading a book and the author is generating a Symfony project running

**composer create-project symfony/symfony mava/**

It seems that it install symfony 3.0.1 for him (last stable version).

After he ran this command he says that a structure like below is generated

mava(project root) folders below as subdirectories
        app
     bin
src
 web
  vendor

When I run the same command symfony 4 is installed and my folder structure is not even close similar to his, only src and vendor folders are the same. I've already tried to specify the version

**composer create-project symfony/symfony mava ^3.0.1**

and

**composer create-project symfony/symfony mava ^2.0**

But I got the same structure, only src and vendor folders.

What is happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the wrong package, for Symfony 3.* it should be `symfony/framework-standard-edition`, not `symfony/symfony`

By using a caret `^` composer will install Symfony 3.4, use tilde instead `~` or a fixed version `3.0.1`
Read more about it here: https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/versions.md#next-significant-release-operators

`composer create-project symfony/framework-standard-edition mava 3.0.1`

Keep in mind that Symfony 3.0.1 is **not maintained anymore**.

Comment: That's it! I know that Symfony 3.0.1 is not maintained anymore but I follow the book and afterward I will read the docs to see what have changed!

Comment: @DiegoAlves Do yourself a favor and follow a different book.  No point in learning Symfony 3 unless you plan to maintain legacy apps.  Especially not 3.0 which is basically the same as 2.8.

Comment: Did symfony change that much in  recent versions? How can a technology that is known to stand out as one of the best implementations of MVC have much to change.., it will be the "internal mechanics"?  I am learning Symfony because I am going to implement an e-commerce using Prestashop 1.7.4 and it uses Symfony 3.4.